# SQL JOIN using COUNT

Tags: sql

I want to use sql `JOIN` with `COUNT` in a way that using the `COUNT` as the condition for the `JOIN`.

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1
  INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl2) t2
  ON (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl1) > 0
```

Is this possible or can someone please tell me another way?

PS- The real question I'm having is that I have two tables A and B and I need to select id from A where the date of creation is greater than some value. At the same time I want to make sure that table B does not have that id in table A. This works fine but when I have no data in table B, the query gives no result.

```
SELECT a.user_id from (SELECT * FROM A WHERE DATEDIFF(event_date,'certain_value') >=another_value) a INNER JOIN B b ON a.user_id != b.user_id
```

I tried to use count like this but failed

```
SELECT a.user_id from (SELECT * FROM A WHERE DATEDIFF(event_date,'certain_value') >=another_value) a INNER JOIN B b ON count(B.user_id) = 0 OR a.user_id != b.user_id
```

Comment: Can you explain what's happening with `ON (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl1) > 0`

Comment: What is the relation between tbl1 COUNT() and tbl2?

Comment: I cannot make much sense of it right away, though it is definitely a possibility: anything that produces a boolean can be used as a condition in a join. It would be easier to see if you do need a join like that if you shared the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: You need some key to join the tables.  Your ON statement should actually be a WHERE clause.

Comment: Try to explain what you are trying to accomplish in english, perhaps with some example data. It's difficult to make an assumption on what type of query you want from your brief question. It seems like you want to use a WHERE clause instead of a join condition. Are you familiar with SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your query is written, condition in `ON` is doing nothing and equivalent to `ON (1=1)` (if there is no records in tbl1, `select * from tbl1 inner join tbl2 on [any condition]` will always return empty resultset).

From your updated question I think you need:

```
SELECT
    a.user_id
FROM
    (SELECT *
     FROM   A
     WHERE  DATEDIFF(A.event_date, 'certain_value') >= another_value) AS a
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM   b
                WHERE  b.user_id = a.user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.user_id
FROM A
WHERE DATEDIFF(A.event_date,'certain_value') >= another_value)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT B.user_id FROM B Where A.user_id = B.user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

"Inner joins return rows only when there is at least one row from both tables that matches the join condition." What you want is is an OUTER JOIN so that you get results even when there is no data in B. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213228%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx

If I understand your question correctly though you may want to use:

```
WHERE a.user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM B)
```

for your condition rather than doing a join on the tables since you're not selecting any data from B at all